# Error While building APK ionic/cordova Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

While building andoird app using commands

`ionic build android` or `cordova build android`command terminates with `Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT`

[image]

Previously it was working fine.. I made some changes in `PATH` variable and after that it's giving the error.

I reinstalled the node, uninstalled and reinstalled cordova.

`ionic platform add android` giving `platform already added.`

Any way to get the exact error or how to solve this. I don't remember my old `PATH` variable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem...

Adding `C:\Windows\System32` to `PATH` variable solved the issue.